# Proper way of using sass with Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

At first, I have written all css styles in one file but things get complicated so I have divided my sass files to folders. I found an article from internet and I followed it. It says "if we put _ in front of sass file, it will not indexed by compiler"

- Created 3 folders
- Created files _test_name.scss like that
- Created _index.scss file for every folder and import all other scss
  files in that folder
- Created main.scss file and import all index.scss files in it.

Everything is working fine **but** if I use color variable in somewhere in other folder it didn't wok. It gave me undefined variable error message. After that I imported colors scss file then it worked. But that's strange right? It should work without importing colors scss file. Now the thing is if I see my styles in developer tools, the **same style repeating three times**! Please check image

[image]

Am I did something wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Using [Sprockets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) directives does not work well with SASS.

> Sprockets provides some directives that are placed inside of comments
>   called `require`, `require_tree`, and `require_self`. DO NOT USE THEM IN
>   YOUR SASS/SCSS FILES. They are very primitive and do not work well
>   with Sass files. Instead, use Sass's native @import directive which
>   [sass-rails](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails) has customized to integrate with the conventions of your
>   Rails projects.

So the first thing you should do is get rid of any sprockets directives in your `application.scss` and [leave the compilation to SASS](http://sass-lang.com/guide)*. This is the most likely explanation to why you are seeing the same styles applied three times as `require_tree .` slurps up any partials.

So instead you should do:

```
@import "test_name"
```

`sass-rails` provides globbing features which can be used to require all partials in a directory as well.

```
@import "mixins/*" 
@import "mixins/**/*"
```

However its usually better to manually import your dependencies as the loading order is hard to determine.